# Which laptop should I buy once my macbook died

Tags: laptop, linux, macbook

recently my macbook pro 2013 died
And I would like to ask what should I do, buy a new macbook pro, or move on to another laptop? I am not going to use windows probably just a linux or osx depending in which I buy...

I used that macbook basically for programming in python and c++ and using various computationaly intensive programs

Can you give me some guidance?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the money, I would recommend the macbook pro with the m2-max processor. It has all the power that you can possibly need, and the battery life/power consumption is amazing compared to Intel based laptops.

Comment: Yup, your last one survived 10 years, why would you look anywhere else? BTW, we still have Macs here as old as 2008, still earning their keep.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the only thing is that I am bioinformatician and most of the tools are optimized for linux so, here is my big doubt, so  which laptop with using linux could compete with macbook pro? To make some comparision and know if it really worth?

Comment: are they not optimized for mac as well? the mac os is built on top of BSD, which essentially is linux. on your other question, it depends on your budget (of course). look into ASUS, MSI, Alien Ware... even some Dell workstations. check out the spec sheets and take your pick.

Comment: Yes and not, most of them works well in both of systems, but some packages are not fully update on mac, anyways I've always been able to deal with it so is not a problem at all. Thanks a lot

Comment: Another question related to this, I have some colleagues with  MSI but they had some problems installing some linux, it happens frequently with this laptops?

Comment: it does have a rep for not being the most stable machine, both in software and hardware, but personally, i have never had an issue with it in that perspective.  (tho i have never run linux on one). also the battery on MSI is by far not the best (due in part to its intel processors), but otherwise, its a pretty neat machine.

Comment: ps. please accept the answer if it is what you were looking for. thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the answer here is "it depends". While your concern about linux is reasonable, the simple reality is that most laptops are going to offer basically the same performance for the same hardware. I.e., my Dell XPS 15 9520 (2022 model) with a 12700h, 64 GB of Ram, 6TB of SSD space, and a 3050 ti is going to run about the same as any other laptop with those specs.

Coding in and of itself isn't particularly demanding. Unless you are doing advanced coding that requires highly parallelized processes that would utilize high core counts, an i5 would likely suffice and and i7 would be a bit more leg room in terms of performance. However, if you're also going to be running a VM on your laptop in order to run a linux distro, you might consider going i7 or i9 (or Ryzen 7 or 9). Peronally, I would avoid going with Apple as they are rather expensive, their compatability is limited (though you would know if the programs you need work on apple), and there is absolutely no upgrade path.

With most windows machines you will be able to upgrade RAM and SSD storage to increase your abilities later. You would likely not have any need for a high end GPU if all you're doing is coding (again, you owuld know if your case is an exception). As such my two primary suggestions would be to either look into a Dell XPS 15 as the build quality is great and the keyboard is amazing, or look into a company called Framework. Not only do they sell laptops with high end CPUs without the high end GPU to jack up prices, virtally every aspect of it is user repairable and upgradable. You can upgrade your ram, storage, monitor, and even the mainboard (I do not believe that the CPU can be replaced without replacing the mainboard tho). And, if you decide you want a GPU or more storage or more battery life, the most recent models allow for an external module to be attached to the rear of the laptop to expand capabilities.

You could also get a last gen laptop in this range for a bit less (a 12th gen i7 is what I have).

Your budget will dictate what you're likely to be able to get, but its likely that a current gen i7 or R7 will last you a few years at minimum.

The recommendation for a workstation laptop is not something I would endorse as they are generally intended for computer modeling and graphical rendering and would be overkill and a waste of money.

Beyond this (and the primary reason why I have abstained from recommending specific brands or models (except hte dell as I can speak to its quality and features) is that the main differences between models and brands is the accessory features such as cameras, I/0, deck flex, monitor specs, etc and those are generally up to personal preference. Like for me, I pefer Dell's lack of USB-A ports and the presence of the SD card reader. You may not care as much. You're going to have to shop around a bit to find a laptop with the ports and stuff that you like/need, but ASUS, Dell, Razor (kind of overkill), Framework, all make decent laptops. The other "gaming" brands like gigabyte and  MSI, to my knowledge, focus solely on gaming laptops, but you don't have a need for the GPU (unless you want to be able to game or do other graphic intensive work).